# faunas of Vivotera part 1: the plausibility of the "Serlano"

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, fauna

so I'm starting a speculative zoology project. It will occur in an alternate earth called Vivotera (from latin of *vivus*=life and *terra*=earth), very very similar to our earth except with faunas that are total different. I'm gonna focus on some of the large and mid-sized animals that can fight back.

my first fauna is called a "Serlano", sheep-sized and herbivorous hoofed mammals, I'll not go to details but here's are some of its description:

- their adapted to live in grasslands, like living in herds and running very fast to survive from predators.
- They can also deliver a strong kick and able to detect a predator from its back
- both male and female can ram , to establish dominance (headbutting each other) and protect its herd from predators for male and to protect its calf for female. both sexes have horn, although is not built to gore

**so my questions:**

1. **is it plausible for my "Serlano" to exist on our earth?**
2. **if yes, what physical traits / anatomy that my "Serlano" required to deliver a strong ram, run fast, delivering a strong rear kick and can detect a predator from its back?**
3. **EDIT: can it have a rear body of a donkey and a front body of a bighorn sheep or a goat?**

Comment: You've just described goats (yes they kick, if you've ever tried milking one then you'll know). What do you mean "detect a predator from it's back" - goats have fine hearing and eyes placed to the sides for near all-round vision, and tend to keep alert to being watched. I'm not sure what you're asking here, please clarify.

Comment: Adding up on what @ARogueAnt. said, every feature you described is pretty common among grazing herbivores from our very Earth. Good news is that the Serlano is really plausible, congrats! Stuff in some vestigial structures that make them unique and voilá, a new animal.

Comment: You do know that cattle (and most ruminants) have a field of view of about 330°, yes? And that they kick something fierce?

Comment: I think you are describing deer, gazelle, or goats. Yes, it’s plausible.

Answer (score 3):

I will extend on my comment here as an answer to actually, well... answer the question properly. So here we go.

### Is it plausible for the animal to exist on Earth?

**Yes**. Grassland herbivores on earth need to have some, if not most, of the features you described. They have to be fast, possess some form of defense (Kicks, horns to gore or to ram, stomps) and most common of all, a field of view that's almost 360º.
[image: horse vision]
This is the view range of a horse. Notice that only a slight turn of the head is able to fill the blind spot on the back. All that leads us to:

### What features it needs to be able to do all that?

**To deliver a strong ram**, it needs strong resilient horns that protect the cranium. Like those of a bihorn sheep as you will mention later.
**To run fast**, you generally can approach it in two different ways:

1. Slender figure and legs like springs. Such as a gazelle.
2. Muscular legs and body. Such as a horse.

Since you also need it to **deliver a strong kick** the muscular legs are the way to go. Lastly, for **detecting a predator** from its back it just needs to have the famous herbivore eyes as stated above.

### Can I have X, Y and Z in my animal?

While I am not an expert in biology to answer how unlikely or how likely combinations of animals are in reality, as a writer I am very confident in saying that you can do whatever fantastical wonder you want with your story.

In real life evolution brought us to the shapes and sizes we are used to, but in your own world it could have taken another turn. Be creative, mix and match. Be it a donkey bum, a woolly coat or a bushy tail. Whatever makes your story interesting and wondrous is fair play.